# Is there a working pimcore nginx config for ddev?

Tags: nginx, pimcore, ddev

I need a nginx-config file for ddev running pimcore. I tried it with the pimcore docs.

https://pimcore.com/docs/5.x/Development_Documentation/Installation_and_Upgrade/System_Setup_and_Hosting/Nginx_Configuration.html

No success here...

Got:

Failed to restart xxxxxx: web container failed: log=, err=container /ddev-xxxxxx-web unhealthy.

I did add a config file in .ddev/nginx/server.conf.
The version of ddev is v1.10.2
The version of pimcore is the latest pimcore 5.

```
upstream php-pimcore5 {
    server unix:/var/run/php-fpm.sock;
}
```

I want to use the nginx servertype for faster usage of pimcore...

Comment: What you need is a phpstatus stanza added to the nginx config, see https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/latest/users/extend/customization-extendibility/#providing-custom-nginx-configuration.  "The location ~ ^/(phpstatus|ping)$ { block is required for the webserver container healthcheck to work."  There are also ways to just turn off the healthcheck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used this .ddev/nginx-site.conf (based on the config in https://pimcore.com/docs/5.x/Development_Documentation/Installation_and_Upgrade/System_Setup_and_Hosting/Nginx_Configuration.html) and it seems to work OK.

BTW, I had never used pimcore before, but was able to

- `ddev config --project-type=php`
- Put the file below in .ddev/nginx-site.conf
- `ddev composer create pimcore/demo`
- `ddev config --docroot=web`
- `ddev restart`
- Install pimcore with `ddev ssh` and `export PIMCORE_INSTALL_MYSQL_HOST_SOCKET=db:3306; vendor/bin/pimcore-install`

and there it was.

Here's .ddev/nginx-site.conf:

```
# mime types are covered in nginx.conf by:
# http {
#   include       mime.types;
# }
map $http_x_forwarded_proto $fcgi_https {
    default off;
    https on;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name _;
    root $WEBSERVER_DOCROOT;
    index index.php;

    access_log  /var/log/access.log;
    error_log   /var/log/error.log error;

    # Pimcore Head-Link Cache-Busting
    rewrite ^/cache-buster-(?:\d+)/(.*) /$1 last;

    # Stay secure
    #
    # a) don't allow PHP in folders allowing file uploads
    location ~* /var/assets/.*\.php(/|$) {
        return 404;
    }
    # b) Prevent clients from accessing hidden files (starting with a dot)
    # Access to `/.well-known/` is allowed.
    # https://www.mnot.net/blog/2010/04/07/well-known
    # https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5785
    location ~* /\.(?!well-known/) {
        deny all;
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
    }
    # c) Prevent clients from accessing to backup/config/source files
    location ~* (?:\.(?:bak|conf(ig)?|dist|fla|in[ci]|log|psd|sh|sql|sw[op])|~)$ {
        deny all;
    }

    # Some Admin Modules need this:
    # Database Admin, Server Info
    location ~* ^/admin/(adminer|external) {
        rewrite .* /app.php$is_args$args last;
    }

    # Thumbnails
    location ~* .*/(image|video)-thumb__\d+__.* {
        try_files /var/tmp/$1-thumbnails$uri /app.php;
        expires 2w;
        access_log off;
        add_header Cache-Control "public";
    }

    # Assets
    # Still use a whitelist approach to prevent each and every missing asset to go through the PHP Engine.
    location ~* ^(?!/admin/asset/webdav/)(.+?)\.((?:css|js)(?:\.map)?|jpe?g|gif|png|svgz?|eps|exe|gz|zip|mp\d|ogg|ogv|webm|pdf|docx?|xlsx?|pptx?)$ {
        try_files /var/assets$uri $uri =404;
        expires 2w;
        access_log off;
        log_not_found off;
        add_header Cache-Control "public";
    }

    location / {
        error_page 404 /meta/404;
        add_header "X-UA-Compatible" "IE=edge";
        try_files $uri /app.php$is_args$args;
    }

    # Use this location when the installer has to be run
    # location ~ /(app|install)\.php(/|$) {
    #
    # Use this after initial install is done:
    location ~ ^/app\.php(/|$) {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_buffers 16 16k;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME $fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors off;
        # fastcgi_read_timeout should match max_execution_time in php.ini
        fastcgi_read_timeout 10m;
        fastcgi_param SERVER_NAME $host;
        fastcgi_param HTTPS $fcgi_https;
    }

    include /etc/nginx/monitoring.conf;
}
```